# RFID received signal strength

Tags: java, rfid, rssi

I am doing a research on RFID (radio frequency identification) positioning system. I need RSSI (received signal strength) in y work. In order to collect RSSI I have to have reader, Antenna, and tags in the real world. I don't have such equipment now to be able to collect RSSI. 
So I want to know is there any way to have RSSI using simulator.

Regards, gilnaz

Comment: Sure, take a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/connections/product_detail/product_35951.html) Matlab package.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help....

Comment: Dear BrOSs, have you ever worked with CISC RFID ASD Kit+Library that introduce me before? as you know RSSI can be affected by environmental factors like multipath, reflection, absorption and so on. my aim is to simulate RSS as similar as real RSS ... so my question is : "Is that possible to simulate RSS considering all this environmental factors  in available simulators like the one you mentioned to get simulated RSS as similar as real RSS??"